# Broken grub after duplicate root repartition

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

My root partition (`sda5`) became to tight for me and I decided to expand it. Unfortunately, after I resize `/home` (`sda6` partition), I understood I cannot expand `sda5`, because of fragmentation.
So I created partition sda8 on unallocated space, and did  #`cat /dev/sda5 > /dev/sda8` 
Next, I resized `sda8` to all available space  `resize2fs /dev/sda8`
After that, I opened `sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and replaced old UUID to new one (same as old, but with "1" on ending).
After that I was able to remove old `sda5` entirely, but I "just" renamed `sda5/grub` to `sda5/_grub` (just in case)
And now I cannot boot because of the following error:
error: file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` not found.
As I understand, the system tried to find grub on `sda5`...

> ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================
>
> => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at
>   sector 1 of 
>       the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
>       in partition 112 for .
>   sda5:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> File system:       ext4
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
> Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
> Boot files:        /etc/fstab
> ```
>
> sda8:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> File system:       ext4
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
> Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
> Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab
> ```
>
> ============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================
>
> Drive: sda
>
> ---
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System
>
> /dev/sda1    *          2,048       718,847       716,800   7 NTFS /
>   exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda2             718,848   112,334,847   111,616,000
>   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda3         112,336,894   234,440,703
>   122,103,810   5 Extended /dev/sda5         112,336,896   132,879,864
>   20,542,969  83 Linux /dev/sda6         132,882,432   169,746,431
>   36,864,000  83 Linux /dev/sda7         210,274,304   234,440,703
>   24,166,400   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda8         169,748,480
>   210,272,255    40,523,776  83 Linux

Comment: At the minimum you will need to reinstall grub, so MBR can find new UUID. (partition 112 obviously does not exist). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Probably best to use advanced mode and total un-install/reinstall of grub2.

Comment: @oldfred did this. Now I have problem with DE. In recovery mode OS able to start Unity via command line (ctrl+alt+F1 #unity), in other ways I cannot able use a terminal.

Comment: Post link to full Boot-Repair Summary Report.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XfYx5bPsFr/

Comment: It looks like sda5 & sda8 do still have same UUID. Best to change one and reinstall grub & edit fstab, if the one you now are booting from. `sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdaX`